# java.lang.AbstractMethodError on Loading XML Configuration (Log4j 2)

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to load XML Configuration from servletContext path, but it somehow just wouldn't load the config. The code is:

```
LoggerContext loggerContext  = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);

File configFile = new File(logConfigurationFilePath);
loggerContext.setConfigLocation(configFile.toURI());
```

Its the setConfiguration() method that throws the exception. I found a somewhat similar thread to this. It suggested to add xercesImpl as a dependency, so I did, but that didn't fix it. The error stack trace is:

```
2019-11-06 14:52:50,199 Thread-13 ERROR Caught java.lang.AbstractMethodError setting feature http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities to false on DocumentBuilderFactory oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilderFactory@67e46b6d: java.lang.AbstractMethodError java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.setFeature(XmlConfiguration.java:204)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.disableDtdProcessing(XmlConfiguration.java:197)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.newDocumentBuilder(XmlConfiguration.java:186)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(XmlConfigurationFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:272)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:408)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:293)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:647)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfigLocation(LoggerContext.java:637)
    at com.att.logicalprovisioning.atc.AnchoredCommonArea.initialize(AnchoredCommonArea.java:130)
```

and

```
2019-11-06 14:52:50,294 Thread-13 ERROR Caught java.lang.AbstractMethodError setting feature http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities to false on DocumentBuilderFactory oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilderFactory@67e46b6d: java.lang.AbstractMethodError java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.setFeature(XmlConfiguration.java:204)
```

and

```
2019-11-06 14:52:50,389 Thread-13 ERROR Caught java.lang.AbstractMethodError setting feature http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd to false on DocumentBuilderFactory oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilderFactory@67e46b6d: java.lang.AbstractMethodError java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.setFeature(XmlConfiguration.java:204)
```

Can you please let me know what can be going wrong here, that it doesn't work, whereas in the other app it does! Thanks!!